# What do I have to do to make multiple network adapters work for a VMWare guest?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, networking, vmware

I have Windows 7 x64 as host and Ubuntu as the guest system.

When I have one virtual network adapter, everything is fine, but if I add a second interface, then only the first is working.

I need two interfaces: auto-bridged (to outer network) and private to the host OS.

Comment: Can you expand upon "only first working?" What kind of traffic are trying to send (IE is it just webpages that aren't loading ect.)? are there any error messages? Have you considered the fact you need to tell the os which adapter to use with with static routes?

Comment: I can't ping any resource. ifconfig don't show ipv4 address of second(eth1) interface. No, I don't know how to configure routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with the following command:

```
ifconfig eth1 "ip"
```